# RW IOSFramework tutorial possible bug using bundle?

Tags: ios

Trying to build my own framework, i followed this tutorial
https://github.com/sammyd/RW-iOSFramework/blob/master/BuildAFramework.md
on how to build a framework.
and i noticed there is an issue with loading images from bundle

I downloaded the final result at
https://github.com/sammyd/RW-iOSFramework/

and after running the app i noticed that the 'ribbon' image isn't shown.

placing a breakpoint at RWRibbonView.m at

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RWUIControls.bundle/RWRibbon"];

result in image = nil.

anyone know how to extract the image from the bundle ? or direct me to a different tutorial ?

p.s before testing, i changed the scheme to the aggregate and build it just to make sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to manifest itself in Xcode 6 - where, rather than copying the resources bundle into the dev app (as expected) it instead attempts to link against it. You can see the problem in the following image:

[image: Linking instead of copying]

You can fix this by dragging **RWUIControls.bundle** from the "Link Binary With Libraries" section to the "Copy Bundle Resources" section:

[image: Correctly places resources bundle]

Note that this change has been made in the repo on Github, so you should not have any problems if you pull the latest changes.

https://github.com/sammyd/RW-iOSFramework

Hope that helps

sam